# How to change Button's Image when mouse is over in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

> I have a button contained two ellipse (Outer ellipse and Inner
>   ellipse) and center of these ellipes is an image i want to make this
>   button like rounded button,and i want to change image when mouse in
>   over the button and below is my xaml code I'm new in WPF and XAML and
>   i know it's not perfect way but any tips can help me to improve my
>   knowledge

```
  <Style x:Key ="roundButton" TargetType ="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property ="Foreground" Value ="Black"/>
            <Setter Property ="FontWeight" Value ="Bold"/>

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/505050.png"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property ="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType ="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Ellipse Name ="OuterRing" Width ="30" Height ="30" Fill ="Black"/>
                            <Ellipse Name ="InnerRing" Width ="27" Height ="27" Fill ="WhiteSmoke"/>
                            <Image Name="im"/>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property ="IsMouseOver" Value ="True">
                                <Setter TargetName ="OuterRing" Property ="Fill" Value ="black"/>
                                <Setter TargetName ="InnerRing" Property ="Fill" Value ="black"/>                                
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property ="IsPressed" Value ="True">
                                <Setter TargetName ="OuterRing" Property ="Height" Value ="33"/>
                                <Setter TargetName ="OuterRing" Property ="Width" Value ="33"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

> It's not working,when mouse is over only ellipses color and size
>   changed but image stay as it beside even if it's work it's not really
>   useful because i want to use this style on many button so in previous
>   code i already gave it image source so it's not helpful, below is my
>   Design XAML code

```
   <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="WhiteSmoke" Margin="10,10,10,0" CornerRadius="5">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button x:Name="btnDataBase" Margin="20,0,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource roundButton}">
                            <Image Source="/Images/5050.png" Width="20" Height="20"/>                              
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
```

> As i said I'm new in XAML and WPF and all above codes got from many
>   searching on google so i don't know what's the better way to do this
>   button,help me please
>   [this image for the rounded button when mouse is not over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFaqK.png)
>   [and this image for the rounded button when mouse is over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgCzo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Style Trigger to change the Image source when the IsMouseOver property is true should work. Try something like this:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource roundButton}">
    <Image Style="{StaticResource btnImageStyle}" Width="20" Height="20"/>                              
</Button>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}" x:Key="btnImageStyle">
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="Image1"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="Image2"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```